# IE error message: "This website has been reported as unsafe"

Tags: c#, asp.net, internet-explorer-9, iis-7.5, internet-explorer-10

I have written a site in C# asp.net and I am running it of IIS7.5.

Site works perfectly well with other browser than IE9 and IE10. In these browsers i get this error message:

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/16/unsafefilterss.png/

The site is http://filterss.net

I am kinda at a loss and I do not really know what I need to change in my programming to make this warning go away. Anyone has any experience with this error?

The obvious question is: "Have i programmed inn malicious software on my site?", No, i have not. Can my programming be exploited? well, yes i would think so, since there is no 100% safe way of coding.

Is there then any concrete reason for this message to appear? Anything that i can change in my code so that it will go away?

Comment: there always the case that a bad plugin, or a virus to add some code to the page (after come to the computer) a spam, a link, something like that, and for that reason you get this error. I have see this happens with sites like amazon. The error was inside the computer by a plugin of the browser that was something like virus.

Comment: Don't agree that this is off topic....

Comment: @Aristos: I have antivirus running on the computer, there is no plugins whatsoever. I have used .NET Framework 4. As my only framework.

Comment: @Simon: I can also not understand how this relates to programming. I am asking what i can change in my code to make this error go away..... how is that not "generally relating to programming or software development in some way" ?

Comment: @BjørnØyvindHalvorsen I think that is not relative to programming, but relative to virus or bad configuration, or you have lose something bad inside it that is not made by programming but by something different like the download of a program

Comment: @BjørnØyvindHalvorsen did the problem solved after you remove the torrent keyword ?

Comment: @Aristos: no, not yet anyways. I have also tried to report that the site is not a threat to microsoft. said it could take two days, so i am just waiting...

Comment: Its working now. Had to send a request to remove it to microsoft. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing i can think of at the moment is that you have torrents in your meta keywords tag

Comment: hmm... I will try to remove this and see what happens. That this should appear because of a meta tag seems ridiculous to me... but it's definitley worth a try.

Comment: This is IE we're talking about here. I can only imagine that `(sourceCode.contains('torrent'))?website=illegal:website=ok;` more mature browsers possibly understand that things like linux distros are distributed via torrents